# How to Remove Duplicates from ICollectionView using FilterEventArgs MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, filter, duplicates, icollectionview

I have two Properties in my `Vehicle` Model: `Category` and `Name`.

I have an ICollectionView called `VehiclesView`.

When bound to `Category`, the ListView displays:

```
Airplane
Helicopter
Helicopter
Airplane
Car
Car
```

I must be able to filter the `VehiclesView` to remove duplicates of the same `Category` which will result in:

```
Airplane
Car
Helicopter
```

Requirement: The filtering logic must use FilterEventArgs, like this:

```
 public void ApplyFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        Vehicle v = e.Item as Vehicle;
        if (v != null)
        {
            // Remove duplicate instances of Category
            if (??????????????)
            {
                e.Accepted = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Accepted = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I only need help with the Filtering Logic.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1:  'Category' is user defined, which means the filter must compare the property values at runtime and remove the duplicates.

EDIT 2: Added links to all research performed, none of which provide the Filter logic I require, but do offer other types of filtering logic and the "Big picture" of how to implement filtering/sorting/grouping.

https://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/wpf-listcollectionview-for-sorting-filtering-and-grouping

http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html

[C# - how to get distinct items from a Collection View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756641/c-sharp-how-to-get-distinct-items-from-a-collection-view)

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26673.wpf-collectionview-tips.aspx

http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/woring-with-icollectionviewsource-in.html

[Implementing a ListView Filter with Josh Smith's WPF MVVM Demo App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188623/implementing-a-listview-filter-with-josh-smiths-wpf-mvvm-demo-app)

[http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/02/23/filtering-in-mvvm-architecture/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AlkampferEng+%28Alkampfer%27s+Place%29&utm_content=Google+Reader](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/02/23/filtering-in-mvvm-architecture/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20AlkampferEng%20%28Alkampfer%27s%20Place%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader)

Comment: Is it WPF? UWP? Which framework are you using? Also, why are you required to use `FilterEventArgs`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering For duplicate entries in ICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663640/filtering-for-duplicate-entries-in-icollectionview)

Comment: @CorentinPane Thanks for the response. I am using WPF with MVVM.  FilterEventArgs best fits the solution I require.  I have red the link you have provided and it does not provide a solution as `Category` in my case is user defined.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26673.wpf-collectionview-tips.aspx#Slightly_more_Complicated

Comment: @Andy  Thanks for the reply Andy.  I have read that article and several others.  They offer the big picture, which is great, but they do not address my question.  I only require the Filter Logic to remove duplicates.

Comment: Sometimes you only get the concept. As a good developer you should be able to develop a solution based on this concept. A developer is not a master of copy & paste. There are times when your solution doesn't exist or was not published by somebody.

Comment: @Slip The link I posted is to part of the article which shows you code compares each entry to the previous one and gives you one entry per level. Which is admittedly not cut and paste but is rather more specific than just the big picture. It does rely on the order of entries without using a dictionary or hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lookup table:

```
private HashSet<object> ExistingItemsTable { get; } = new HashSet<object>();
private void ApplyFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
  if (this.ExistingItemsTable.Contains(e.Item))
  {
    // FilterEventArgs.Accepted is true by default
    e.Accepted = false;
    return;
  }

  this.ExistingItemsTable.Add(e.Item);
}
```

You need to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event of the source collection to maintain the lookup table: when items are removed you also need to remove them from the table.

Comment: You could use just a HashSet rather than a dictionary. A hashset is something developers relatively rarely come across and is "just" the keys and all you need to identify a category which has already been seen.

Comment: @Andy Thank you for the suggested improvement. I have updated the example to replace the `Dictionary`.